# Show multiples of a given number within a range

Tags: loops, kotlin, foreach, collections, range

How can I fix the following code in better way (alternative way to iterate range from first element to last element? My goal is to write kotlin code in most efficient and simplest way

I am looking someone tell me instead of n/7 what should I write to get the same result of code

```
val numList =  1..20
val numMul7= numList.map { it *7 }

// here what else instead of n/7 can i use to get same result and it iterate the range from the first element to the last one
numMul7.forEach { n -> println("${n/7} * 7 = $n") };
```

here there is the output:

```
1 * 7 = 7
2 * 7 = 14
3 * 7 = 21
4 * 7 = 28
5 * 7 = 35
....
12 * 7 = 84
13 * 7 = 91
14 * 7 = 98
15 * 7 = 105
16 * 7 = 112
17 * 7 = 119
18 * 7 = 126
19 * 7 = 133
20 * 7 = 140
```

Edit 2:
@Saurabh Patel or any other expert
Can you please let me know why following code doesn't work?

```
val numList =  1..20
val numMul7= numList.map { it *7 }
numMul7.forEach { n -> println("${it} * 7 = $n") };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```
(1..20).map { it * 7 }.forEach { println("${it/7} * 7 = $it") }
```

Or the same with just `forEach` function:

```
(1..20).forEach { println("$it * 7 = ${it*7}") }
```

If you need to save result in a variable:

```
val listOfMultipliers = (1..20).map { it * 7 }
```

If we use more abstract way:

```
fun getMultipliersBy(range: IntRange, multiplier: Int): List<Int> {
    return range.map { it * multiplier }
}

// we can call it like this
getMultipliersBy(1..20, 7).forEach { println("${it/7} * 7 = $it") }
getMultipliersBy(1..40, 10).forEach { println("${it/10} * 10 = $it") }
```

Using **extension function**:

```
fun IntRange.getMultipliersBy(multiplier: Int): List<Int> {
    return map { it * multiplier }
}

//call it like this
(1..20).getMultipliersBy(7).forEach { println("${it/7} * 7 = $it") }
(1..40).getMultipliersBy(10).forEach { println("${it/10} * 10 = $it") }
```

Comment: Great response!

Answer (score 1):

This can be what you are looking for

```
val numList =  1..20
numList.forEach{
    println("${it} * 7 = ${it*7}")
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer your code is much lighter than me , i will accept your answer as respond of this thread but just last question, i am  just curious, for learning purposes if i have to use map , how can i iterate? can you edit your post and show me if i have to use map , how the answer would be, Thanks

Comment: i edit my question to clarify my meaning , please see edit 2 , Thanks

Comment: @Jack In your edit 2 , you have used name 'it' incorrectly. Refer to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) for more info

Comment: I refered to your link , but can't find the answer, please let me know how can i correct the edit2, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this code, you have a typo:

```
val numList =  1..20
val numMul7= numList.map { it * 7 }
numMul7.forEach { n -> println("${it} * 7 = $n") }
```

Should be:

```
val numList =  1..20
val numMul7= numList.map { it * 7 }
numMul7.forEach { n -> println("${n} * 7 = $n") }
```

You cannot use `it` in the `forEach`, because you named the variable `n`.

Or, the same thing can be done using `it`:

```
val numList =  1..20
val numMul7= numList.map { it * 7 }
numMul7.forEach { println("$it * 7 = $it") }
```

Comment: Sorry , not working as desire  your answer produce this in output which is different from my goal: 7 * 7 = 7     ---------    14 * 7 = 14 ------ 21 * 7 = 21 .....

Comment: Facepalm. I didn't run the code. You won't be able to use `numMul7.forEach` without undoing your multiplication. You should use `numList.forEach` instead or `numList` and `numMul7`.

Answer (score 0):

after playing with the code ,this is another way , but Sergey answer is most cleanest one, Thanks

```
    val numList =  1..20
    val numMul7= numList.map { it}
    numMul7.forEach { n -> println("${n} * 7 = ${7*n}") };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily keep track of both the original and calculated value to then print it and map to the calculated value:

```
val numMul7 = (1..20).map { it to it * 7 }.map { (orig, calc) ->
    calc.also { println("$orig * 7 = $calc") }
}
```

the scope function `also` is used for the side effect of logging the results and does not do anything to `calc`.

Comment: What version are you using? I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. fwiw, I'm on 1.3 but pretty sure it would run with >= 1.1